# iOS in MessageComposer add image and text

Tags: ios, mms

I want to send MMS in iOS and for that I will be using Message Composer API.
Now I can send mms by adding text in body and image as attachment.

But I want to send message which will be combination of image and text:
ex :
 Hi [image] how are you [image] .

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Sending MMS via [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) is available in iOS 7 only:

First check if you can send MSS with the [`canSendAttachments`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMessageComposeViewController/canSendAttachments) method:

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendAttachments]) {
    // YES we can send a MMS
}
```

The easiest way is to use [`addAttachmentURL:withAlternateFilename:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668-CH1-SW16) to attach attachments to you messages. You are not able to get your image in the middle of the text.